# How to make GDB use a RAM dump file?

Tags: gdb, crash-dumps, coredump

We have an embedded board with ColdFire CPU which runs µC-OS/II. When the embebbed program crashes, the CPU dumps (or copies) the entire RAM in the embedded flash. Then, we have a procedure to retrieve the RAM content (which was dumped into the flash) into a simple .bin file.
When we want to debug, we use GDB (m68k-elf-gdb.exe) combined with the .elf file. For example :

```
$ gdb our_elf_file
(gdb) print some_var
Cannot access memory at address 0x30617890
(gdb) ptype some_var
type = unsigned int
(gdb)
```

This allows us to know the address of the variable. Then, we perform a simple offset operation with the previous given address and read the RAM dump at a specific location. 
For example, if we want to read **some_var** located at *0x30617890*, we know that the dump represent the RAM content starting from *0x20000000*. After that, we read 4 bytes of the .bin file at the offset (*0x30617890* - *0x20000000*).
(Sometimes we also use objdump (m68k-elf-objdump.exe) for other purposes).

I am completely new to this kind of stuff so maybe my question is stupid, but, is there some way to tell gdb where the RAM content is ?

Comment: Perhaps the `section` command might help: http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-section-1044

Comment: It does not tell that I can specify that a section is in another file, plus, I don't think that my .bin file has the appropriate format.